# Can we modify a database while a connected Excel file is open?

Tags: excel, ms-access, oledb

I have an access file with different queries.
I connected the access queries to an excel file.

When I open the excel file, and the access file on the same time, I cannot perform any modification on the access file since the excel file was open first.

Is there a way to change that?

Comment: Apparently not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we create a connection from an Excel document to an Access database the default setting is `Mode=Share Deny Write`:

[image: Connection Properties]

You can change that by opening the Excel document, selecting the connection via

Data > Connections > Properties… > Definition

and then editing the entry in the "Connection string" to be `Mode=Share Deny None`.

As always when changing default settings like that, it is your responsibility to ensure that such a change will not cause problems somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: I just have a follow up question if possible - If I change this to <Mode = Share Deny None>, Will I still be able to modify the Excel file without issue? What is the only change that happen when I write <NONE> instead of <WRITE> ? I would like to know the kind of impact that this change can have. Thank you again.

Comment: That's a very good question and is precisely the reason I included the last paragraph in my answer. I showed you how it *can* be done but it's up to you to determine whether it is a "good idea"™ in your particular case. 